# How to pass nulllable Unit object to kotlin function via java

Tags: java, kotlin

Hello I am integrating following kotlin code into java code

this is kotlin code

```
 PickupManager.getInstance().configure(this)
```

getinstance is define like this in kotlin lib

```
 public final fun getInstance(arg: A? /* = compiled code */): T { /* compiled code */ }
```

when I need to write java equivalent to this code I got following error

```
 PickupManager.Companion.getInstance(new Object()) .configure(this);
```

required Unite found Object

so how to pass Unit parameter to getinstance() method in java

Comment: What did you have in `/* = compiled code */`? If the default value is null, just pass null. Or in the Kotlin code, mark the function `@JvmOverloads`.

Comment: /*= compile code */ its 3rd party lib code don't have access to it

Comment: Do you have access to its documentation?

Comment: https://www.radiusnetworks.com/developers/flybuy/#/sdk-2.0/android